# how to insert Gridview in iFrame c# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I created a website in **c#** and it contains a **gridview** which displays data from the database. I want that this GridView will in a **iFrame** shown. This iFrame will be of course in the same page. I started with **jQuery** the last 2 days.
I found that the iFrame requires always `"src=..."`.
so how can I insert only a **GridView** in the **iFrame** please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6uOM.png)

Bellow is about what I need to build..and in the iFrame will be the Gridview depending on the two textBoxes "name" "vorname"

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate page which contains GridView only. Now create another page which will have iframe tag whose src will set for the last page of GridView.
Let say: Default.aspx will have the gridview 
now create a new page default2.aspx which will have below HTML

```
<iframe src="default.aspx"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I had the same idea but Default.aspx contains textBoxes(firstname,lastname) and my gridView displays data from database depending on those two textBoxes strings..how can I do my works in this case?

Comment: Textboxes will be added on the parent page which will have only Iframe. And you can set the Textboxes value to iframe source as querystrings using some jQuery. These querystring can be get on other page and get the grid view filled based on that.

Comment: var url = "default2.aspx?textbox1="+$("#textbox1ID").val()+"&textbox2="+$("#textbox2ID").val()
$("#iframeid").attr("src",url)

Comment: thank you..I have added a screenshot of what I want really :)